# Creating a Neo4j Graph Database Using LOAD CSV

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, nodes, graph-databases

I have a CSV file containing the data that I want to convert into a graph database using Neo4j. The Columns in the file are in the following format :

**Person1 | Person2 | Points**

Now the ids in Person1 and Person2 are redundant , so I am using a Merge statement instead. But I am not getting the correct results. 
For a sample dataset , the output seems to be correct , but when I import my dataset consisting of 2M rows, it somehow doesn't create the relationships.

I am putting the cypher code that I am using currently.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/Users/yogi/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/sample.csv" AS csvline
MERGE (p1:Person {id:toInt(csvline.id1)})
MERGE (p2:Person {id:toInt(csvline.id2)})
CREATE (p1)-[:points{count:toInt(csvline.c)}]->(p2)
```

Comment: Your query looks correct. Are the nodes created properly?

Comment: Hey @MartinPreusse , the nodes are getting properly created , but the number of relationship shows 0. Maybe I am missing some 200 nodes out of the total 35,000 nodes too.

Comment: For the sake of troubleshooting you could split up creation of nodes and relationships in two queries. See the link from Stefan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you should check:

1. are you using an index: `CREATE INDEX ON :Person(id)` should be run before the import
2. depending on the Neo4j version you're using, the statement might be subject to "eager-pipe" which basically prevents the periodic commit. For more on eager pipe, see http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

Comment: The eager thing actually worked . I tried creating the nodes first and then matching them to create the relationships.